# Python - Regular Expression, how to extract this?

Tags: python

I have this kind of string

```
str = "(\\pt 3 \\out I1, I2 \\img img.jpg)"
```

I would like to extract 3 , I2, I2 and img.jpg as a separate values(I1, and I2 as one value)

I started like this

```
pattern = "\\pt (.)"
re.findall(pattern, str)
```

and I get first value 3, but can't figure out how to extract the other two?

Comment: Which parts of `str` are always static. I.e, can you provide more examples of strings that need to be matched, or perhaps a template that describes the format of the string.

Comment: This is the template str = "(\\pt [value1] \\out [value2[ \\img value3])"

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex

```
>>> re.findall(r"\\\w+ ([^\\)]+)", str)
['3 ', 'I1, I2 ', 'img.jpg']
```

The part you are missing is, you need to understand

- what to fetch `[^\\\)]+` everything except a `\` and `)`
- how to begin `\\\w+` two slash followed by any word followed by a space

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: -

```
>>> pattern = '\\\w+ ([^\\)]+)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, s)
['3 ', 'I1, I2 ', 'img.jpg']
```